# Vulgar Username

Tags: support, etiquette, user-accounts, deletion, complaint

I think necessary steps should be taken against the profile https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26920/urine-soaked-pajamas as the user name and avatar are offensive and go against the dignity of the forum.

Comment: I agree with you but I couldn't help notice several far more vulgar users names [on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users) (just try searching a few standard vulgarities).

Comment: @Macro Moderators generally only act on possibly offensive user names or avatars if someone complains. If nobody complains, moderators don't actively search for violations of the site rules.

Comment: @MadScientist: Different people are offended by different things. Some people are offended just because the other user is from a certain country or of a certain religion. Other people are offended by political statement done on this platform (using user name or user profile)...

Comment: I was surprised that Harry Potter's Erect Nipples survived as long as it did. Note there is currently an Ilyk Coitus and a few others. I believe I commented on one of his "I like slapping people."

Comment: @WillJagy, pretty sure this is the same guy

Comment: This is great.  Is there a list of the usernames before they disappear?

Comment: @AsafKaragila these decisions can get rather complicated, there are a few hard rules but many cases fall into an area where the moderators have to make a judgment call.

Comment: I downvoted this question because I disagree that the user name or avatar are offensive or go against the dignity of the forum. I believe it is seen such because of excessive tabooization of excretion, which might not only be seen as unnecessary, but also as harmful. Links:[1](http://www.rug.nl/news-and-events/people-perspectives/opinie/2010/opinie31-2010?lang=en),[2](http://www.healthy.co.uk/articles/2013/01cp-urinary-incontinence.html),[3](http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/2012/02/27/holding-your-pee-health-_n_1299435.html)

Comment: I cannot edit the comment anymore, but I just wanted to share [this](http://www.thepsychologist.org.uk/archive/archive_home.cfm?ArticleID=2076&editionID=214&volumeID=25) article as well.

Comment: @Q__: I could be wrong, but I doubt that the nickname urine-soaked-pajamas was chosen to further the awareness of incontinence; more likely it was chosen for shock value. The avatar accompanying this nickname seems to support this doubt. My guess is that most of the other socially inappropriate nicknames are not meant to support some socially progressive cause. I have no problem talking about incontinence or similar problems, but I don't think a math Q&A site is the proper place.

Comment: @Q__ on the other hand, the name is chosen precisely because of the taboo. Can you imagine the person naming himself Water Soaked Pajamas? If it weren't for the taboo, th name would not be chosen, and this reason would just have chosen another "taboo" name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to see how StackOverflow views this issue, I looked up a few discussions of offensive usernames and gravatars on MSO. They might be applicable:

[Possibly offensive usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117596)

[Inappropriate username and/or gravatars.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147519)

[Offensive Username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103292)

Comment: Oh my gosh, I am laughing so hard at this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117617/178175 .  It makes me want to change my name to *asshole* for a week, then change it back.  So then there would be comments like "@asshole what's the point taking the derivative first?".

Answer (score 7):

For entertainment and for more serious purposes, here is a CW list of the known names and results.  The case of known censored substrings is omitted; they can be detected by a script and the results are more predictable.

Move cursor over spoiler-space to view.

> Dropped on Japan (SO, renamed "Dropped on Caprica", bomb gravatar unchanged)
>
>  Harry Potter's Erect Nipples (MSE, (moderator?) renamed)
>
>  Ylyk Coitus (MSE, active)
>
>  urine soaked pajamas (MSE, moderator renamed "pajamas", finger salute gravatar unchanged)

Comment: Uses of a list (other than amusement and a chronicle of user creativity) include recording what kind of names draw complaints, what judgements the moderators make when their hand is not forced, having data for later cases, and preserving some erased history.  If there exists any "community standard", better to know what it is and is not.

Answer (score 1):

Edited. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$